# Guessing password within 10 tries

Tags: probability, statistics

> A password is either 4, 5, 6 characters long, and can only contain 2, 3, 5, 7 and **must contain at least 1 two.** Find the probability that your friend guesses the password within 10 attempts.

There are a total of: $5364 - 1044 = 4320$ possible passcodes that work.

But how do I fit in the 10 attempts?

First try + second try + ... + tenth try?

$=1/4320 + 1/4319 + .. + ?$

Im not sure, would like help!

Comment: A style comment on writing out numbers: it's confusing to say that it must contain "at least 1 two". Much clearer and more standard would be, "at least one 2".

Compare to the situation where the password entries are not integers but symbols: $\square, \bigcirc, \triangle$. Which is better, "at least 1 square", or "at least one $\square$"?

Answer (score 3):

The total number of passwords should be the number of 4-6 digit passwords using the characters 2, 3, 5, and 7 minus the number of passwords using just 3, 5, and 7. For this you compute

$$(4^4 + 4^5 + 4^6) - (3^4 + 3^5 + 3^6) = 5376 - 1053 = 4323.$$

The probability that your friend guesses on the first attempt is $\frac{1}{4323}$, as you said.

The probability that your friend guesses your password on the second attempt is the probability that she guesses wrong on the first attempt *and* right on the second attempt. That's $\frac{4322}{4323}\cdot\frac{1}{4322} = \frac{1}{4323}$.

Similarly, let's say you look at the third attempt: you want the probability that your friend guesses wrong on the first and second tries, and then guesses your password on the third try. That happens with probability $\frac{4322}{4323}\cdot\frac{4321}{4322}\cdot\frac{1}{4321} = \frac{1}{4323}$.

The same pattern continues: assuming your friend guesses a different password every time, the probability that she guesses on the $n^\text{th}$ attempt is $\frac{1}{4323}$.

Now, as you suggested, you can add the probabilities corresponding to the first try + second try + ... + tenth try, since you want to know the odds that she guesses right on the first try *or* the second try *or* the third try, and so on.

This gives you a probability of

$$10 \cdot \frac{1}{4323} = \frac{10}{4323}.$$

Comment: Rather than counting each attempt individually with fractions, one can simply skip to the end and say that there are $10$ distinct attempts out of a possible $4323$ combinations, for a final probability of $\frac{10}{4323}$.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you counted correctly:

The probability that he misses the first attempt is $\dfrac{4319}{4320}$, the probability he misses the second is $ \dfrac{4318}{4319}$ and so on.

The probability he doesn't guess is the product of all these fractions, almost everything cancels and you get $\dfrac{4310}{4320}$. Therefore the probability he guesses is $\dfrac{10}{4320}=\dfrac{1}{432}$